# pd.ExcelFile sheet_names in for loops in python

Tags: python, pandas

```
xls = pd.ExcelFile(file_path)
sheet_names_needed = [] 
for i in xls.sheet_names:
  if len(i) < 4:
    sheet_names_needed.append(i)
df = pd.read_excel(file_path,sheet_name=i,skiprows=6,usecols=range(0,3)) 
print(df)
```

Hi! I want to do operations in some worksheets in an Excel workbook, for example, plotting the same type of chart in every sheet. The code I wrote is aimed to select the sheets that I want to use. But it only reads the last sheet in the workbook. Why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
xls = pd.ExcelFile(file_path)
for i in xls.sheet_names:
  if len(i) < 4:
    df=pd.read_excel(file_path,sheet_name=i,skiprows=6,usecols=range(0,3)) 
    print(df)
```

it is becuase you are giving the read_excel outside the loop and then you are using iterator variable to mention sheet name which is the last element of the list generated by xls.sheet_names (i.e the last sheet)